# How to perform multiplication and division of "superlong" integers?

Tags: c, arrays, int

Consider the need to deal with integers that can have hundreds of digits. Let us call them "super long" integers. Clearly they cannot be stored using the data types like int or long int.
A "super long" integer can be read in as input from the user, digit by digit, and stored in an array with each digit of the super long integer occupying one location in the array. The problem involves taking two positive "super long" integers as input from the user, digit by digit. Each digit is entered by the user as a character. The end of the positive "super long" integer is signified by the input and storage of the $ symbol.

Here you may assume that the maximum number of digits that the positive super long integer would occupy is 25 digits.

Write a C program that is capable of performing the following operations on these positive super long integers.

1. Add two positive super long integers
2. Subtract one positive super long integer from another positive super long integer
3. Multiply two positive super long integers
4. Divide one positive super long integer by another positive super long integer
5. Provide the remainder of a division of one positive super long integer by another positive super long integer
6. Find the maximum of two positive super long integers

I am done with writing functions for performing addtion, subtraction and maximum of two positive superlong integers. I am unable to perform multiplication and division to get quotient and remainder separately.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: It looks pretty much like a homework assignment, with no effort at all applied to it so far, and still no question.

Comment: 'I am unable to perform multiplication and division to get quotient and remainder separately.' Didn't you learn long multiplication and long division in school?

Comment: @Patashu Yup. I have done coding for such problems for 8051 microcontroller. I am not forte at doing it in C.

Comment: @Maverick How would you write it out in 8051? How would you write it out in psueodocode/pseudo-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any solid large integer implementations in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191002/are-there-any-solid-large-integer-implementations-in-c)

Comment: C: combining the flexibility and power of assembly language with the user-friendliness of assembly language.

Comment: @Patashu In pseudocode using the programming instructions for 8051... The opcode and mnemonics...

Comment: @Maverick C lets you write inline assembly, maybe it would be easier that way - http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use GMP library if you are not able to write your own function,

http://gmplib.org/

use it and you will be sorted....

Answer (score 0):

Result of all expression will be very big number which beyond the range of even long int or long double.  you have to store such a big numbers in c using array. you have to use same logic that is we are using to multiply two numbers except instead of storing the data in the normal variables we are storing into the array.

below are some referenced link:

http://www.cquestions.com/2010/08/multiplication-of-large-numbers-in-c.html

http://www.cquestions.com/2010/08/division-of-large-numbers-in-c.html

http://www.thinbasic.com/community/showthread.php?11206-C-multiplying-big-integers

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/114679-multiplying-huge-numbers-integer-arrays.html

[Extremely big integer multiplication and addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985058/extremely-big-integer-multiplication-and-addition)